# FileDialog doesn't show after get input from console

Tags: java, console, user-input, filedialog

When I want to open a FileDialog after I get some input from the console it fails.
See the code below.
When I first call `openFileDialog` and then `chooseOption` it works fine.
Does anybody know how this is possible?

```
public class SomeClass
{
int choice = 2;
Scanner keyboard;
String filter = "*.xml";

public void mainMenu() {
    keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);      
    choice = ChooseOption();    
    FileDialog loadDialog = openFileDialog("Choose file", filter);

    useInfo(loadDialog);
}

public int ChooseOption() {
    System.out.println("Make your choice: \n"
                        + "0) option A \n"
                        + "1) option B");

    try {
        choice = keyboard.nextInt();
    } catch(Exception e) {          
        System.out.println("Invalid input, try again.\n");
        ChooseOption();
    }
    return choice;
}

public FileDialog openFileDialog(String title, String filter) {
    System.out.println("Which file you want to use? \n");       

    FileDialog loadDialog = new FileDialog(new Frame(), title , FileDialog.LOAD);
    loadDialog.setFile(filter);
    //loadDialog.pack();
    loadDialog.setVisible(true);    

    return loadDialog;      
}

public void useInfo(FileDialog loadDialog) {
    if( loadDialog == null || loadDialog.getFile() == null ) {
        useDefaultFile();
        doSomthing();
    } else {
        doSomthingElse();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: It doesn't display at all, the code look likes it in an infinite loop. But it doesn't crash

Comment: it seems to work fine as far as showing the dialog

Comment: Post full class so people can try and quickly see the problem.

Comment: @melc but it doesn't show, weird enough.

Comment: @Makky if I run the above code it still doesn't work. This is all you need. Mayby change the mainMenu in main(String[] args). I will fix that

Comment: Is it possible the program is just waiting for an input, but because maybe you didn't prompt an for an input with System.out.println, you're not expecting to require an input?

Comment: I tried it and when I entered 1 it displayed an extra frame. What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: @peeskillet no, because in debug mode it continues when the user give a number as input

Comment: @Makky Strange, it won't display when I run the code

Comment: There should be frame , may be its behind other windows.

Comment: @Makky indeed, it is. Thanks!

Comment: @Makky if you post it in an answer I will accept it, so this question can be closed.

Comment: I've replied it . Upvote and accept thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FileDialog` is displayed as  `frame` but it might be behind other `Active Windows.`

Answer (score 0):

The following code works using jdk6,

```
import java.awt.FileDialog;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Dialog {

    int choice = 2;
    Scanner keyboard;
    String filter = "*.xml";

    public void mainMenu() {
        keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        choice = ChooseOption();
        FileDialog loadDialog = openFileDialog("Choose file", filter);

        useInfo(loadDialog);
    }

    public int ChooseOption() {
        System.out.println("Make your choice: \n"
                + "0) option A \n"
                + "1) option B");
        try {
            choice = keyboard.nextInt();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input, try again.\n");
            ChooseOption();
        }
        return choice;
    }

    public FileDialog openFileDialog(String title, String filter) {
        System.out.println("Which file you want to use? \n");

        FileDialog loadDialog = new FileDialog(new Frame(), title, FileDialog.LOAD);
        loadDialog.setFile(filter);
        loadDialog.setModal(true);
        //loadDialog.pack();
        loadDialog.setVisible(true);

        return loadDialog;
    }

    public void useInfo(FileDialog loadDialog) {
        if (loadDialog == null || loadDialog.getFile() == null) {
            System.out.println("useDefaultFile();");
            System.out.println("doSomthing();");
        } else {
            System.out.println("doSomthingElse();");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dialog d = new Dialog();
        d.mainMenu();
    }
}
```

It is highly possible that when the dialog is shown it is behind other active windows.